# Xamarin forms slow calculations

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin forms and i have simple program that make calculation:

```
public static double KosinosovaTeorema(double ABNadZnamenatel, int ABPodZnamenatel, double ACNadZnamenatel, int ACPodZnamenatel)
        {


            double V_Znamenatel_NadLiniq = 2 * ACNadZnamenatel * ABNadZnamenatel;
            int V_Znamenatel_PodLiniq = ACPodZnamenatel * ABPodZnamenatel;
            return  V_Znamenatel_NadLiniq +  V_Znamenatel_PodLiniq ;
        }
```

But after clicking button in my forms ,above code takes around 3 seconds to show results.Why it is taking so much time for such simple calculation ?

Here is button event

```
 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            pich.Text = Class1.KosinosovaTeorema1(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3);

        }
```

Comment: Anything else happening in the button click? What happens to the return value? Are the numbers immediately available or are they being fetched?

Comment: i just only call this method and program doesn't show it at same time

Comment: Show some more code,it is not enough

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="PracticeXamarinForms.Views.CalculationPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label x:Name ="result" 
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            <Button Text="Click Me" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>

using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace PracticeXamarinForms.Views
{
    public partial class CalculationPage : ContentPage
    {
        public CalculationPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            result.Text = Convert.ToString(KosinosovaTeorema(1, 2, 3, 1));
        }

        public static double KosinosovaTeorema(double ABNadZnamenatel, int ABPodZnamenatel, double ACNadZnamenatel, int ACPodZnamenatel)
        {
            double V_Znamenatel_NadLiniq = 2 * ACNadZnamenatel * ABNadZnamenatel;
            int V_Znamenatel_PodLiniq = ACPodZnamenatel * ABPodZnamenatel;
            return V_Znamenatel_NadLiniq + V_Znamenatel_PodLiniq;
        }
    }
}
```